# How to create a direct integration between an API Gateway and SQS in Python Chalice

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, chalice

I have an app that I am building using Python Chalice and would like to create a direct integration with the REST API gateway and an SQS queue without using a lambda function. My code for the gateway is as follows:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    data = json.dumps(app.current_request.json_body)
    queueURL = SQS.get_queue_url(QueueName=os.environ["INPUT_QUEUE_NAME"]).get('QueueUrl')
    resp = SQS.send_message(QueueUrl=queueURL, MessageBody=data)
    return resp
```

I am using `bobt3` to send the data obtained from my endpoint to an SQS queue but on AWS it integrates directly to a Lambda function rather than an SQS queue. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You have written code that takes a post to the root route and adds it to an SQS queue in Chalice. Chalice is a serverless framework for Lambda, so any function you create in Chalice is run in a lambda. Are you asking how to respond to handle the items in the queue?

Answer (score 0):

chalice can't set up the integration between API Gateway and SQS. Chalice deploy serverless python and minimal configuration to support the deployment.

In order to achieve that you will need to do it using the AWS console/AWS CLI or deploying a cloudformation / terraform

**How to with cloudformation**

https://www.matthealy.com.au/blog/post/api-gateway-sqs-integration-cloudformation/

**How to with AWS Console**

https://medium.com/@pranaysankpal/aws-api-gateway-proxy-for-sqs-simple-queue-service-5b08fe18ce50